# Unresolved reference on class property

Tags: kotlin

My code:

```
open class Team (val country: String = "England",
            val aggressive: Boolean = true, 
             name: String, squadSize: Int = 24) {

    val attendance: Int

    init {
        if (aggressive){
            attendance = 25000
        } else {
            attendance = 20000
        }
    }

}

fun chooseTeam(team: String) {
    val homeTeam = Team(name = "Blue Team")
    println("the home team is ${homeTeam.name} so they are ${if(homeTeam.aggressive) "angry" else "timid" }")
}
```

I'm getting an `Unresolved reference: name` on `${homeTeam.name}`.

However I've specified the `name` when I instantiate the class `val homeTeam = Team(name = "Blue Team")` - any idea why I'm getting unresolved reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin you need to put `val`/`var` before any property inside the primary constructor, otherwise the property wont be declared as a member variable.

Please correct it:

```
open class Team(
    val country: String = "England",
    val aggressive: Boolean = true,
    val name: String,
    val squadSize: Int = 24
) {
   ...
}
```